# My list as a default list for wiki pages

Tags: wiki-pages

I would like my list containing audio and video content types to be the default list for wiki pages (I tuned the list to support wiki content type as well).

Currently if I try to create a wiki page inside the list, the item is placed under SitePages instead.

How do I change the default location?

Comment: How did you add your wiki content type exactly? Which content type you've added?

Comment: I did it using VS2012 and then imported the wsp file into sharepoint. Actually I created my own content type derived from Wiki Page (0x010108)

Comment: @Naim, thanks, I'll try it in a few hours and let you know about the result

Answer (score 1):

Create a Wiki page Library (ServerTemplate=119) and use Wiki Page content type there.

After you get that working try adding the other content types to this wiki library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.
If you try deleting the default SitePages library, you'll see that the New Page button on the Site Actions menu will disappear.
That is because the wiki pages feature needs two default libraries, Site Pages and Site Assets.